# Isn't [timing] and [code-timing] really the same thing?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

The [timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timing) and [code-timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-timing) tags seem to be about the exact same thing. Am I wrong?

I don't have enough rep with them to suggest one as a synonym of the other.

Comment: If we make it a synonym, I would say timing should be the master. However, not sure if this tag is to broad and should be burninated instead.

Comment: Is timing really necessary?

Comment: @Braiam: No, it is merely an illusion. If we can only transcend it, surely we shall reach enlightment.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the questions with these tags and determined that they are, *in practice*, used to mean the same thing? Or are you merely basing it on the names of the tags? I'm with you on the latter, but before I merge/synonymize, someone needs to verify that they are actually being used to mean the same thing. If not, a manual clean-up needs to be done first, before we destroy the evidence.

Comment: @CodyGray: Well, I looked at the titles of a bunch of them. Also, at the fact that only one of the tags has a description.

Comment: I wanted to post a meta question about burninating [timing] for quite some time… it’s used for a very broad set of topics: working with dates; as a synonym for [performance]; order of execution; delays; as a synonym for [scheduled-tasks] and lots more…

Comment: @Xufox: +1. Onwards and upwards. File it then.

Comment: [tag:code-timing] is now a synonym of [tag:benchmarking]. Would that be fine, or do we need to relook this one?

Comment: @BhargavRao: That's actually wrong IMHO. A benchmark is something that _may_ involve timing code. I'd undo that synonymization.

Comment: It was proposed and approved by the community, so I am kinda helpless here. Sorry!